# Is it possible to change the value of a selection field dynamically in Odoo 10?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I would like to have my selections depend on the value of a Char field, for instance, a Char field defined as such:

```
my_char = fields.Char("Enter Something", readonly = False)
```

so I suppose the selection field should call a function, something like "_get_value"

```
my_selection = fields.Selection(selection = ' _get_value')
@api.model
def _get_value(self):
    my_list = [('key1','value1')]
    #no idea how to assign the value of my_char to value1
    return my_list
```

Eventually, I would like to have the selections in the drop down list vary as the user input different strings in my_char.
Is this achievable in Odoo? Because if it's not, I should better start reorganizing my structure. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If the user writes *option_1* in `my_char` field and then modifies it to write *option_2*, should your selection list be `[('option_1', 'OPTION 1'), ('option_2', 'OPTION 2')]` or `[('option_2', 'OPTION 2')]`?

Comment: You should use `many2many` instead of `selection`

Comment: @forvas the latter ~

Comment: @qvpham well what I want to realize is once the user typed down a string, he/she can select the same string in a drop down list in the same page, how can I do that in one page if those belong to 2 models? Tks

Comment: @yesterday: okay, you can do it with 2 models. It's not really a problem. Selection must be predefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far is i know, it isn't possible with field type `Selection`. But you can use a `Many2one` field for such a behaviour.

```py
class MySelectionModel(model.Models):
    _name = "my.selection.model"

    name = fields.Char()

class MyModel(models.Model):
    _name = "my.model"

    my_char = fields.Char()
    my_selection_id = fields.Many2one(
        comodel_name="my.selection.model", string="My Selection")

    @api.onchange("my_char")
    def onchange_my_char(self):
        return {'domain': {'my_selection_id': [('name', 'ilike', self.my_char)]}}
```

Or without a onchange method:

```py
    my_selection_id = fields.Many2one(
        comodel_name="my.selection.model", string="My Selection",
        domain="[('name', 'ilike', my_char)]")
```

To let the `Many2one` field look like a selection, add the `widget="selection"` on that field in the form view.

How the domain should look like, should be decided by you. Here it is just an example.

Comment: You forgot double quotes when you define `string` attrinute on the last field.

Comment: @CZoellner First of all, thanks for the answer. I've copied pasted the codes(I've tried both, onchange and without onchange) and it doesn't seem to work however. I added a field in XML for `my_char` and typed something inside and clicked away to let it save but the drop down list remains empty.

Comment: Did you create some records for the selection model? Without them nothing can be shown or selected.

Answer (score 0):

No need to write method here. Just declare the dictionary to a variable and call it in selection field.

```
VAR_LIST = [('a','ABC'),
            ('p','PQR'),
            ('x','XYZ')]

my_selection = fields.Selection(string="Field Name",VAR_LIST)
```